# Dedicated server not available external

Tags: networking, dns

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

So what I am simplying trying to setup a pc as a server. I setup the dns record of the domain to my external IP. On my router I set the portfowarding to the pc

Dns settings:
[image]

Port forwarding:
[image]

external ip -> internal ip, TCP port 80

When I look through my browser evertyhing works. (through domain and external IP).

But when I look from an other network I just get a white page. I used [is up](http://isup.me/) and that says the same the site is not available.

So can some one explain what I am missing here, because I am quiet new and well couldn't find the answer any where

Comment: Your port forwarding looks wrong. What kind of router to you have?

Comment: The router/modem i have is the Ubee EVW 3200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.

What was wrong was the ip address.

I set it to only accept my ip (83.87.245.244).

But I had to change it to 0.0.0.0 so all ip's are accepted

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as answered after 48 hours.